# How to load a python module with arguments in python?

Tags: python, module, python-module, argv

I would like to create a python module that would be called with `python -m mymodule somefile.py some_arg some_arg`.

The idea is that I would be able to set up an alias `alias="python -m mymodule"` and call files normally with `python somefile.py some_arg some_arg`.

In the file `mymodule/__main__.py`, what is the best way to load `somefile.py` and pass it the argument list?

- I am looking for a generic solution, that would be python2 and 3 compatible.
- It would be great to be as little intrusive as possible. If `somefile.py` would raise an exception, `mymodule` should barely be seen in the traceback.
- What the module does is not interesting here in detail, but it sets up some python things (traceback hooks etc.), so `somefile.py` should be ran pythonicly in the same process. `os.system` or `subprocess.Popen` do not fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found something good for python 3.5, and satisfying enough for python 2.7.

#### mymodule/**main**.py

```
import sys

# The following block of code removes the part of 
# the traceback related to this very module, and runpy
# Negative limit support came with python 3.5, so it will not work
# with previous versions.
# https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/traceback.html#traceback.print_tb
def myexcepthook(type, value, tb):
     nb_noise_lines = 3
     traceback_size = len(traceback.extract_tb(tb))
     traceback.print_tb(tb, nb_noise_lines - traceback_size)
if sys.version_info >= (3, 5):
    sys.excepthook = myexcepthook

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    file = sys.argv[1]
    sys.argv = sys.argv[1:]

    with open(file) as f:
         code = compile(f.read(), file, 'exec')
         exec(code)
```

#### somefile.py

```
import sys
print sys.argv
raise Exception()
```

#### in the terminal

```
$ python3 -m mymodule somefile.py some_arg some_arg
['somefile.py', 'some_arg', 'some_arg']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "somefile.py", line 3, in <module>
    raise Exception()

$ python2 -m mymodule somefile.py some_arg some_arg
['somefile.py', 'some_arg', 'some_arg']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/runpy.py", line 184, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/azmeuk/dev/testpy/mymodule/__main__.py", line 16, in <module>
    exec(code)
  File "somefile.py", line 3, in <module>
    raise Exception()

$ python somefile.py some_arg some_arg
['somefile.py', 'some_arg', 'some_arg']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "somefile.py", line 3, in <module>
    raise Exception()
Exception
```

Still, if someone has a better proposition, it would be great!

Comment: It is a good solution. Make sure to add as little names as possible in the global dictionary of `mymodule/__main__.py` because `somefile.py` doesn't expect these objects in its namespace. You could also play with the `limit` argument in `traceback.print_tb` to display a clean traceback.

Answer (score 1):

I think the negative value of `limit` does not work in traceback module before python 3.5. Here is an ugly hack that works with python 2.7

```
import sys
import traceback

class ExcFile(object):
    def __init__(self, file):
        self.topline = True
        self.file = file

    def write(self, s):
        if self.topline:
            u, s = s.split('\n', 1)
            self.file.write(u +'\n')
            self.topline = False
        if '#---\n' in s:
            u, s = s.split('#---\n', 1)
            self.file.write(s)
            self.write = self.file.write

ExcFile._instance = ExcFile(sys.stdout)    
# The following block of code removes the part of 
# the traceback related to this very module, and runpy
def myexcepthook(type, value, tb):
    traceback.print_exception(type, value, tb, file=ExcFile._instance)
sys.excepthook = myexcepthook

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    file = sys.argv[1]
    sys.argv = sys.argv[1:]

    with open(file) as f:
        code = compile(f.read(), file, 'exec')
        exec(code) #---
```

All this should be written in a separate file, to avoid clutter `__main__.py`.